# Google Documents List API file upload (411error - weblogic)

Tags: google-docs-api

I have question about Documents List API.

We use Docs api In our internal system. That system use WebLogic(Oracle).

Docs api is very well running about basic functions like create,listing, ect.

But file upload function has some problem at webLogic.

There is no problem in other environment.(we tested at Tomcat & Jave).

Here is my source and error Log.

** source **

```
private DocumentListEntry uploadGoogleDocumentFile(String url,
      String file, DocsUploadProgressListener listener, int progressUpdateInterval)
      throws IOException, ServiceException, InterruptedException {

    // Pool for handling concurrent upload tasks
    ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_CONCURRENT_UPLOADS);

    File f = new File(file);
    MediaFileSource mediaFile = getMediaFileSource(file);

    mediaFile.setContentLength(f.length());

    ResumableGDataFileUploader uploader = new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(service, new URL(url), mediaFile, null)
    .title(mediaFile.getName())
    .chunkSize(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE).executor(executor)
    .trackProgress(listener, progressUpdateInterval)
    .build(); 

        uploader.addHeader("Content-Length", f.length()+"");
    uploader.start(); <-- error point

    // Wait for completion.
    listener.await();

    // Thread clean up.
    executor.shutdownNow();
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

    if(uploader.isDone())
        return uploader.getResponse(DocumentListEntry.class);
    else
        return null;
```

}

** ERROR Message **

```
<html lang=en>
```

Error 411 (Length Required)!!1
  
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}

**411.** That?셲 an error.

POST requests require a `Content-length` header.  That?셲 all we know.
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:632)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
        at com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.createResumableUploadSession(MediaService.java:630)
        at com.google.gdata.client.media.ResumableGDataFileUploader$Builder.build(ResumableGDataFileUploader.java:250)
        at com.posco.google.documents.v3.DocumentsCore.uploadGoogleDocumentFile(DocumentsCore.java:530)
        at com.posco.google.documents.v3.DocumentsCore.uploadGoogleDocumentFiles(DocumentsCore.java:496)
        at com.posco.google.documents.v3.V3DocumentsManager.uploadFile(V3DocumentsManager.java:171)
        at com.kcube.lib.repo.GoogleDocsRepository.store(GoogleDocsRepository.java:117)
        at com.kcube.mov.ptube.PtubeItemManager.updateAttach(PtubeItemManager.java:98)
        at com.kcube.mov.ptube.PtubeItemUser$GoogleDocsDaemon.execute(PtubeItemUser.java:182)
        at com.kcube.sys.daemon.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:27)